# PostgreSQL - Get registers from last day of the month and the last day case the month isn't over

Tags: postgresql, date

I have several tables, where all the data is recorded day by day.
I need the query for PostgreSQL.

Already tried extract, distinct and interval but it didn't work.

I need the result for every last day (or higher, in case the month isn't over), of every month, of every year.
I have data from 2016 to 2023, with some 'holes', which are being filled in with a Python script.

That's why I need the last day (or the higher recorded), of each month, of each year.

I will not join the tables, I just need the same result for all of them, separately.

Example:
table name = snacks /
today = 2023-03-02

| Name (str) | Amount (int) | Date (date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cookie | 6 | 2016-01-30 |
| Brownie | 4 | 2016-01-30 |
| Cookie | 2 | 2016-01-31 |
| Brownie | 5 | 2016-01-31 |
| Cookie | 8 | 2016-02-01 |
| Brownie | 10 | 2016-02-01 |

(no more data from the month/year 02/2016 and later,
until in the month/year 01/2021, it starts again and follows the pattern until today in the example. The hole in data is being completed)
...

| Name (str) | Amount (int) | Date (date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cookie | 1 | 2023-01-30 |
| Brownie | 5 | 2023-01-30 |
| Cookie | 7 | 2023-01-31 |
| Brownie | 3 | 2023-01-31 |

....

| Name (str) | Amount (int) | Date (date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cookie | 2 | 2023-02-27 |
| Brownie | 8 | 2023-02-27 |
| Cookie | 9 | 2023-02-28 |
| Brownie | 19 | 2023-02-28 |
| Cookie | 6 | 2023-03-01 |
| Brownie | 3 | 2023-03-01 |
| Cookie | 25 | 2023-03-02 |
| Brownie | 30 | 2023-03-02 |

What I need:

| Name (str) | Amount (int) | Date (date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cookie | 2 | 2016-01-31 |
| Brownie | 5 | 2016-01-31 |
| Cookie | 8 | 2016-02-01 |
| Brownie | 10 | 2016-02-01 |
| Cookie | 7 | 2023-01-31 |
| Brownie | 3 | 2023-01-31 |
| Cookie | 9 | 2023-02-28 |
| Brownie | 19 | 2023-02-28 |
| Cookie | 25 | 2023-03-02 |
| Brownie | 30 | 2023-03-02 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to try to receive month in a subquery. In the main query, group by `Name`, `Month` and sort data by `Name`.
Aggregate data by maximum `Date`. Get the `Amount` for this date by extracting the values into an array using `array_agg`(get last value).

```
SELECT name, (array_agg(Amount ORDER BY Date DESC))[1] AS Amount, MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM
(
SELECT *, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) AS Month
FROM table1
) t
GROUP BY name, Month
ORDER BY name
;
```

Get the data of the second table in the same way and combine them with: `UNION ALL`.

```
(
SELECT name, (array_agg(Amount ORDER BY Date DESC))[1] AS Amount, 
MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM
(
SELECT *, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) AS Month
FROM table1
) t
GROUP BY name, Month
ORDER BY name
)

UNION ALL

(
SELECT name, (array_agg(Amount ORDER BY Date DESC))[1] AS Amount, 
MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM
(
SELECT *, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) AS Month
FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY name, Month
ORDER BY name
)
;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7W7zrAiD) is the entire code from creating the table to the result. Also at the very end he gave an example if the order of the lines that was indicated is needed.

**Update 28.03.2023**

Added a `year` to extract to the `subquery`. Also a few `rows for 2023`. Everything is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lKRqX5zO) from table creation to selection.

```
SELECT name, (array_agg(Amount ORDER BY Date DESC))[1] AS Amount, MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM
(
SELECT *, 
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) AS Month,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) AS Year
FROM table1
) t
GROUP BY name, Year, Month
ORDER BY name
;
```

Comment: inquire did not work.
When using the first part of the query, it brings the result for the last day of the month, of the biggest year, but not behind the other years.

Comment: Returned date data:
2021-08-31
2021-09-30
2021-10-31
2021-11-30

However, it has data from other months, from 2016 to 2020 that were not delivered.
So from what I understand, the query is bringing the results of the last day of the month, of the last year (DESC) that has a record.

Comment: What I need is the data from the last (or biggest) day I have in the database, from each month, from each year. Like the example at the beginning of the statement.

Comment: In the question, you didn't say what you need for each year. Then add more data and change the expected result. For every year and months. That is, there will be 12 results per year?

Comment: Sorry inquirer. I've edited the statement again to make it clearer.

But that's right. I need the last day (or the higher recorded), of each month, of each year.

Comment: and the union query will not be necessary, because I will not unite with another table.

Comment: That is, it turns out in general you need for all months. Right?

Comment: Right. I've edited again to make it more clearer.

Comment: See update below. Also a few rows for 2023.

Comment: And by the way, you don't need to worry about 'every last day (or higher if the month has not ended'. The last line after grouping by name, year and month and sort by date will be what you need.